# Assume vs assert in JUnit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have read that `assume` will not run the test if assumption failed,
but I am not sure regarding the logic of when to place `assert` vs `assume`.

For example: any resource loading check should be done with `assume`?

When should I use `assume` over `assert`?

(Note: i am looking for correct design of when to use one over the other)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Assume.assumeTrue or Assert.assertTrue, when do tests exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208492/using-assume-assumetrue-or-assert-asserttrue-when-do-tests-exit)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As you already know, you use `assert` to fail a test if something goes wrong.

You use `assume` if you have circumstances under which a test should not run. "Not run" means that it cannot fail, because, well, it did not run.

So, in a hypothetical scenario where:

- you have different builds for different customers, and
- you have some resource which is only applicable to a particular client, and
- there is something testable about that resource, then

you would write a test which:

- assumes that the resource is present, (so the test will not run on customers that do not have that resource,) and then
- asserts that everything about the resource is okay (so on the customer that does actually have the resource, the test makes sure that the resource is as it should be.)

Technically, both `assert` and `assume` throw exceptions. The difference is that:

- the kind of exception thrown by `assert` will cause the test to fail, while
- the kind of exception thrown by `assume` will cause the test to be skipped.

Answer (score 12):

**The Assert** class is the workhorse of JUnit and is the class JUnit testers are most familiar with. Most JUnit assert signatures are similar in nature. They consist of an optional message, an expected instance or variable and the actual instance or variable to be compared. Or, in the case of a boolean test like True, False, or Null, there is simply the actual instance to be tested.

The signature with a message simply has an initial parameter with a message string that will be displayed in the event the assert fails:

```
assert<something>(“Failure Message String”, <condition to be tested>);
```

**Assumptions**:
You’ve probably heard that it’s best not to work on assumptions so here is a testing tool JUnit gives you to ensure your tests don’t.

Both Asserts and Assumes stop when a test fails and move on to the next test. The difference is that a failed Assert registers the failure as a failed test while an Assume just moves to the next test. This permits a tester to ensure that conditions, some of which may be external and out of control of the tester, are present as required before a test is run.

There are four varieties of Assumes: one to check a boolean condition, one to check that an exception has not occurred, one to check for null objects, and one that can take a Hamcrest matcher. As seen in the Assert section above, the ability to take a Hamcrest matcher is a gateway to testing flexibility.

You can read more here
https://objectcomputing.com/resources/publications/sett/march-2014-junit-not-just-another-pretty-assert/

In short Assume used to disable tests, for example the following disables a test on Linux: `Assume.assumeFalse(System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Linux"));`
Assert is used to test the functionality.

Answer (score 5):

The most easiest difference between Assert and Assume is :

**Assume** will only run when the assumption is true. Will be skipped if it false.

```
assumeTrue(boolean assumption, String message)
```

**Assert** will run normally if true.
In case of false assert, it gives predefined error message.

```
assertTrue(boolean condition, String message)
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply check out the [javadoc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html) for Assume:

> A set of methods useful for stating assumptions about the conditions in which a test is meaningful. A failed assumption does not mean the code is broken, but that the test provides no useful information.

In other words: when an **assert** fires, you know that your testcase *failed*. Your production code isn't doing what you expect it to do.

*Assume* means ... you don't know exactly what happened.